# Is the DAG do calculus rule an axiom?

Tags: causality, dag

Using the 'do calculus' + DAGS framework for causal inference, is this

> **If** $(Y\perp X)_{G_{\underline{x}}}$ **then** $P(Y|X=x)=P(Y|\text{do}(X)=x)$

an axiom? Or can it be proven from first principles (and without using any notation from an alternative framework, such as potential outcomes)?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, *do-calculus* is indeed the first axiomatic formulation for causal inference, see [do-calculus rules (Axioms)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causal-models/do-calculus.html) from Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy's [causal inference](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causal-models/index.html) entry.

The equality asked can be regarded as the special case of the axioms. This is so-called the *back-door criterion* $P(Y|do(X),Z) = P(Y|X, Z) $. But it requires more strict conditions than only independence.

Axioms should provide equivalency to *potential outcomes*, however they have philosophical differences in how they construct solutions of course. One could argue that, DAGs provides more insights in the mechanisms, i.e., explicit causal model.